# Javascript to open file and read something using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, windows-desktop-gadgets

I would like to make a small gadget to use at work and show me the time of check in, from the morning.

I am trying to open a network file using http protocol and read from it the line which is referring to my check in.
This is located on our intranet and can be accessed like this:

```
filename = 'http://www.intranet.loc/docs/dru/Acces/' + ystr + '-' + mstr + '-' + dstr + '.mvm';
```

Every employer has a unique code for check in. The structure of the check In file is like this:

```
12:475663:1306285:072819:11:1:1:0:
12:512362:1306285:072837:11:1:1:0:
12:392058:1306285:072927:11:1:1:0:
12:516990:1306285:072947:11:1:1:0:
12:288789:1306285:073018:11:1:1:0:
12:510353:1306285:073032:11:1:1:0:
12:453338:1306285:073033:11:1:1:0:
12:510364:1306285:073153:11:1:1:0:
12:510640:1306285:073156:11:1:1:0:
```

In this example, 12 is the gate number, which I don't need, the second is my ID, the third is the current date, and what I need is the fourth (the hour).

Edit:
I am using this function to return the content of the mvm file with no luck:

```
function readfile(fileToRead) {

var allText = [];
var allTextLines = [];
var Lines = [];
var Cells = [];

var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
txtFile.open("GET",fileToRead, true);
allText = txtFile.responseText;
allTextLines = allText.split(/r\r\n|\n/);

return allTextLines;
```

}

Comment: How about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split?

Comment: Just split the lines at the `:`, then you can access the individual values in the resulting array by index.

Comment: simple mockup for demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/risto/69Amm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need a RegEx? Would it be possible to split the line by ":"?

```
$.get('http://www.intranet.loc/docs/dru/Acces/' + ystr + '-' + mstr + '-' + dstr + '.mvm', function(data) {
    var lines = data.split("\n"),
        values;

    for (var i in lines) {
        values = lines[i].split(':');
    }
});
```

With this you would have everything you need.

Comment: The thing is that I am currently stuck at grabbing the content of the .mvm file

Comment: You said that this is an http request, where is the problem opening the answer? use $.get(); and in the response you can split the lines and values.

Comment: Could you please, elaborate?

I am using a function readfile (FileToRead)

Comment: You could use jQuery for this. The you could do do something like this: 
`$.get('http://www.intranet.loc/docs/dru/Acces/' + ystr + '-' + mstr + '-' + dstr + '.mvm', function(data) {
  var lines = data.split("\n");
  for (var i in lines) {
    var values = lines[i].split(':');
  }
});`

Comment: For some unknown reason it doesn't work and I cannot do proper debugging because i can only use internet explorer. I am able to grab the content as object but cannot continue from here

Comment: WHich version if IE? IE10 at least has developer console. Otherwhise try installing it from MS.